# How to go through a directory and run an svn delete command if certain file is found?

Tags: svn

So I accidentally committed my eclipse .project and .settings files & directories. Instead of going through each folder in the command line (huge amount of folders) is there a way to go through each folder and if one of those files/directories is found, run a svn delete .project?

I was thinking something like:

```
 find . name ".settings" -exec "svn delete .settings" {} \;
```

but I always get the "No such file or directory error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -iname .settings -exec svn delete {} \;
```

**EDIT:** For your more understanding about `find` command usage:

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ mkdir .settings
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ mkdir -p dir1/.settings
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ mkdir -p dir2/.settings
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ mkdir -p dir2/dir2_1/.settings

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ find . -type d -iname .settings
./.settings
./dir1/.settings
./dir2/.settings
./dir2/dir2_1/.settings

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ find . -type d -iname .settings -exec ls -ld {} \;
drwxr-xr-x  2 sgeorge  wheel  68 Jan 18 21:59 ./.settings
drwxr-xr-x  2 sgeorge  wheel  68 Jan 18 21:59 ./dir1/.settings
drwxr-xr-x  2 sgeorge  wheel  68 Jan 18 21:59 ./dir2/.settings
drwxr-xr-x  2 sgeorge  wheel  68 Jan 18 21:59 ./dir2/dir2_1/.settings
```

Comment: I guess find just passes whatever it finds to -exec so I wouldn't need to put the file name after? Just the command I'd want to execute?

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try and experiment with this a bit.

Comment: see my edit. it will give you more understanding about the usage of `find`

Comment: If answer helped you, make sure that you have accepted the same.

Comment: Recommend any documentation or books to become more familiar with these kinds of intricacy?

I'm coming from development on a Windows machine to Java development on a mac machine so although I know the big ones, its the little stuff like this I'm still getting used to.

Comment: I can suggest some commands you should learn: `sed`, `awk`, `rsync`, `find`, `diff`, some `bash` tricks etc. Following link will help you. http://hoput.blogspot.in/2011/11/bash-scripting.html . Try to search about all above commands and its usage. There are many other handy commands also in Linux/Unix environment which will help you in development.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net), check out your repository to a folder, then identify and revert your changes easily.